# How to release the physical and virtual memory used from the mysql server?

Tags: linux, mysql, memory

Several php scripts are executed via crontab on my CentOS 6.5, every php script contains a least one database request. Depending on the size and type of the php object, too much physical memory is allocated by mysqld service in some specific cases.

Sometimes, there is only 15MB free memory from 1.7GB, the swap memory is also allocated maybe to 95% usage. For releasing the server memory the only alternative solution is restarting the mysqld server, but after couple of days the memory is almost full again.

For ignoring the mysqld restart I've tried to flush the query cache using `RESET QUERY CACHE;` and `FLUSH QUERY CACHE;` but nothing is changed in the memory status. Also I've tried to execute `sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` but the memory status is same again.

Do you know how to release the physical and virtual memory for example after every script execution without restarting the mysql server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's the MySQL eating up all the memory, then you have to tune down its values or increase the server RAM. If you have told MySQL that it can have 16 GB of RAM but only 8 GB is available, well, then things do happen.

You don't keep a party for 20 people in your average hotel room just to find out that the room is too small, and try it again next night hoping you could then fit 20 persons there. You either book a bigger room or invite less people.

Comment: I think this scenario is more often case on my server:  there is available physical memory on the server, but the swap is almost full, and I am supposing that the objects in the physical memory are flushed automatically but not the objects in the swap memory. Any suggestions in this case?

Comment: Are you sure your PHP scripts (or some heavy SQL queries) are not suddenly allocating lots and lots of memory for a while? That would force your system to swap and whenever the heavy query or PHP script (I suspect the PHP scripts) ends, the memory is released and shown as free RAM & used swap. Fix that somehow. :)

Comment: actually your comment is right description for my problem :) . At the same moment a lot of memory is allocated from PHP and mysql. Maybe reducing innodb_buffer_pool_size or some other memory related mysql variable will solve the problem?

Comment: I would go and check the PHP code and the SQL queries it generates first. Enable MySQL query logging if in doubt. It can also be that the SQL queries are efficient but the PHP script is doing something memory-hungry, perhaps by design, perhaps because of a bug.